# Is that the correct way to use TMS in GeoServer

Tags: geoserver, tile-map-service

In GeoServer, I'm not found TMS Demo, so I read the [GeoWebCache doc](https://www.geowebcache.org/docs/current/services/tms.html) about TMS, and following the TMS protocol as the doc mentioned, try to construct the url: http://localhost:8080/geoserver/gwc/service/tms/1.0.0/topp%3Astates@EPSG%3A900913@png/5/5/20.png and request my local GeoServer, and I get the picture successfully from the server. [image]

So my question is: the url above is the correct way for use TMS in GeoServer? In other words, the clients(such as leaflet) use that url format to request GeoServer is the correct way?

> The "topp:states" layer(in url above) is a predefined layer in GeoServer, and I manually seed/truncate the layer using GridSet EPSG:900913.

Edited:

@Ian Turton Is the link you mentioned?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

GeoServer provides a GetCapabilities link on the server home page that provides all the information a client requires to access the TMS service. This is both machine and human readable. There is no need to provide a demo to a well known protocol.

Comment: Is the link in above picture as you mentioned?

Comment: that's the one just click and read it